# Find a prime number with loops

Tags: java, loops, primes, joptionpane

I'am new to Java and my homework was to make a program where the user input a number and the program check if the number is a prime number or not.

I have to use any loop and JOptionPane for input.

I've managed to write this code and it works:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
public class Programmeringsoppgave5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0; 
        String readNumber = showInputDialog("Write a number and exit with ESC");

        while (readNumber != null){
        number = Integer.parseInt(readNumber);
            if (number != 0 && (number == 1 || number == 2)){
                System.out.println("Number " + readNumber + " is a prime number.");
            } else if (number % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("Number " + readNumber + " is not a prime number.");
            } else if (number % 2 == 1){
                System.out.println("Number " + readNumber + " is a prime number.");
            }//end if-test
            readNumber = showInputDialog("Write a number and exit with ESC");
        }//end while    
    } //end method
}//end class
```

I was wondering if there was any easier or better ways to write this program?

Comment: `if (number % 2 == 1){
                System.out.println("Number " + readNumber + " is a prime number.");}` Sorry but this is not the definition of a prime number. 9%2 == 1 but 9 is not  prime.

Comment: After 0, 1, and 2 this is basically just checking if a number is even or odd.

Comment: Ah I see that now. I could allways do many nested ifs and check every primenumber but that is probably very bad programming.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure a number is prime, you need to see whether it's divisible by any of the prime numbers below it.

So you can do something more like having an ArrayList of primes you've found so far, which starts with a hard-coded 2.

Then, you start looping from 3 up, and you test whether each new number is divisible by any of the primes already in your ArrayList. If it's not, you add it and move on to the next. If it is, then you just move forward.

You do this until you get to the number in question.

There are a few optimizations you can perform. For example, when checking for numbers that are the factors of the current number, you only need to go up to sqrt(currNum).

If you want to get fancy, you could implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Thanks! I will have too look at this later when I learn arrays.

Comment: Well, if you want, there is a way of doing it without arrays: for the given number, say, x, loop from 2 to sqrt(x) and check whether any of those numbers can divide x. If none of them can, then it's prime.

The solution I gave in my answer was a little more complicated than it needed to be.